# Could not load file or assembly 'FastReport'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, report, fastreport

the report show correct in my local but when i upload i have problem .

> could not load file or assembly 'FastReport' or one of its
>   dependencies. Strong name signature could not be verified.  The
>   assembly may have been tampered with, or it was delay signed but not
>   fully signed with the correct private key. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80131045)
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or
>   assembly 'FastReport' or one of its dependencies. Strong name
>   signature could not be verified.  The assembly may have been tampered
>   with, or it was delay signed but not fully signed with the correct
>   private key. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131045)

Comment: How did you resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

- right click on FastReport project in Visual Studio
- select Properties in context menu
- go to Signing tab
- uncheck Sign the assembly

Comment: by default its unchecked, what should i do?